# Add image to GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, intellij-idea, jpanel

I'm trying to add an image to a `JPanel` in IntelliJ's GUI editor. I can't find anywhere that lets me do this.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: You do it the same way in Intelli-J as you you do it in Eclipse, or Netbeans, or from the command line.  Or to put that another way, this has *nothing* to do with your IDE.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to add [Image/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the GUI, then better way is put picture(s) to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), links to the tutorials contains examples for that, with for correct usage by [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and resiziable for/with [Top-lavel Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: Thanks, JLabel works a dream. Just remember you are setting the `icon` property, and to clear the text if you didn't want any :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined what "adding an image" means. Is this a background image and other components will be added on top. Do you want the image to fill the entire panel or should the image be painted at its actual size? The approach will be different depending on the answer. Maybe you can use an existing component or maybe you will need to create a custom component.

See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a couple of approaches.

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more specific. I want the image to fill the entire panel. Thanks

Comment: ..and will other components be on top of the image?  Did any of the linked examples fit the use-case?  Geesh.. getting information from you is less pleasant (& harder) than pulling teeth.